# English to lingo and lingo to english conversion

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app,which can convert from english to lingo and lingo to english.Is there any API to do this.What are the best possible ways to do this.

Comment: Google Translate API, for instance

Comment: @nikis Can we convert into lingo.or its paid paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use google apis for this purpose

```
private final String requestURLTranslation = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=";
    private final String requestKey = "INSERT-YOUR-KEY";
    private final String requestSrc = "&source=";
    private final String requestDst = "&target=";
    private final String requestTxt = "&q=";


    public String requestTranslationForGoogle( String plaintext, String source, String destination ) {

        String request = requestURLTranslation + requestKey + requestSrc + source + requestDst + destination + requestTxt;    
        try {
            request += URLEncoder.encode( plaintext, "UTF-8" );
            URL url = new URL( request );
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" );
            BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader( inputStreamReader, 512 );
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
                sb.append( line );
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Note: The code will return the json data which should be parsed further**

please visit

1) https://github.com/Rookery/google-api-translate-android

beside this

2) http://api.yandex.com/translate/

3) http://mymemory.translated.net/

Comment: @ Jitesh Can we convert into lingo through these API.?

Comment: @Swati i think you can do with google translation!! please cross check!!

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You need to post the relevant content in your post as your answer has no value once the link becomes dead in the future. You have enough reputation to post links as comments

Comment: @ Raghunandan you are correct sir but if you will read the question than you can see that in this question it is asked about the possible ways to use apis and asked that is there any api?  so i gave the link means that user can use google translation api and others.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay post it as a comment or delete this. This will be eventually flagged and deleted. Its a problem with the question close the question

Comment: k sure will remark this, please do not delete question as more guys can serach the same that is there any translator api is there or not

Comment: just edit you post with relevant code or delete this altogether

Comment: ok i will give code with this but give me some time that i can write some code